# Is there a way to verticaly occupy all the space of the flexbox container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I want the search button to occupy all the space vertically
I have tried setting the height to 100% of the  parent container but not working, I have tried setting the flex-basis  to 100%/0/auto (not working). Look at my Code below and see the picture of the btn beside the input.

**I want that btn to gain the height equal to the height of the input**

See the Problem here
[image]

**My Html:**

```
<div className="search_subContainer">
      <input
        className="searchCity"
        type="text"
        value={value}
        placeholder="Search city..."
        onFocus={() => {
          setFocus(!focus);
        }}
        onBlur={() => {
          setFocus(!focus);
        }}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button className="search_btn">
        <IoSearch />
      </button>
    </div>
```

**My Css:**

```
.header .search_subContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: stretch;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid brown;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.header .searchCity {
  width: 17em;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.377);
  font-family: var(--secondary-font);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.header .searchCity:focus {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.719);
}

.search_btn {
  width: 3em;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
  border: none;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search_btn:hover {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

Comment: ***OFF Topic ignore my style now currently i am just building the mechanism then i will style the website properly

Comment: https://codepen.io/ullas_/pen/LYQerwd

Comment: No I give a reference,.... and explicit height or width no a good idea

Comment: `height: 100%;` is exactly what messses up your code. you don't need it on the children of a `flex` container because the default behavior of the children is to have `align-self` to `stretch` (In most cases). Remove it from your input and your button.

Comment: Just remove align-items: center; for container and container become stretch. This rule is breaking your button. Then you can align the icon inside the button using flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is caused by `align-items: center`. Adding that to a flex container with a direction of `row` aligns the flex children to the center vertically.

To fix this, remove that line and the search button should align with the input element.

### Fix

```css
.search_subContainer {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid brown;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Doing this also means no need to add a `height` and `flex: 1` to the input container, input element, and button itself.

### So

```css
.search_btn {
  width: 3em;
  background-color: brown;
  border: none;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchCity {
  width: 17em;
  padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.377);
  font-family: var(--secondary-font);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove align-items: center; for container and container become stretch. Then you can align the icon inside the button using flex. It's the simplest and correct way, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

There Your go:

- please avoid explicit height and width

simple:

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh
}
.header{
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.search-bar {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.search-bar::placeholder {
  color: black;
}

.submit-btn {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;

  padding: 11px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-style: none;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<div>
<a href='/'>tanjiro</a>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="search" placeholder="Awesome" class="search-bar">
  <button type="button" class="submit-btn">Search</button>
</div>
</div>
```